# How do you make Ubuntu Server run smoothly with an AMD/ATI ES1000 Graphics card?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, ati

I've been researching this for a while now, and it appears that the reason my Ubuntu Server GUI (ubuntu-desktop) install is *really* slow is because of the AMD/ATI ES1000 Graphics card. I've been looking at a lot of forums and I can't find any real solutions to my problem other than installing lubuntu or xubuntu. I want to know if there is a way to make it run smoothly on Ubuntu, either by installing a new driver, or somehow turning off 3D, or anything?

**SPEC:**
HP ProLiant ML350 G6
CPU: 8 Core 2.4Ghz
RAM: 16035MiB
GRAPHICS: AMD/ATI ES1000

Comment: What kind of machine is this running on? And, since it's a minimal/server install, did you install drivers in the first place? It might just be that you are running the GUI with your CPU handling everything.

Comment: Why would you install Ubuntu Server and then install a GUI? Just stick with a regular desktop version and get proprietary drivers for your hardware, no trouble.

Comment: @sbergeron I added specs to my question. I probably *didn't* install any drivers, how do I do that? (I'm  noob obviously)

Comment: @EduardoCola Sounds simple when you say it that way. How do I do that?

Comment: OK so what GUI do you have? If you installed ubuntu-desktop then just open settings, scroll down to drivers and select either the open source xf86-video-ati or one of the proprietary fglrx drivers. I'm pretty sure that it's new enough to work with fglrx, but if it isn't there are older versions that you can get. Anything done this way is the same thing that a fresh install of the normal ubuntu setup does.

Comment: @sbergeron Yes, ubuntu-desktop, I've opened system settings>Software & Updates>Additional Drivers, and there's nothing. I think I've missed a step...

Comment: does it say there are no drivers available? or is it just not picking up on any device being present? It might even still be loading, as it can take a bit.

Comment: @sbergeron "No additional drivers available"

Comment: OK, in that case you might have to manually install the open source drivers as upon looking it up it seems that it's probably a bit too old to use the proprietary fglrx/catalyst drivers. I'll see if I can find the right package name for them as I'm coming over from arch linux for this and they use a slightly different package naming system for somethings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33420/discussion-between-shemseger-and-sbergeron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 1st suggestion would be ... delete the desktop.

So you are running an ubuntu desktop as a server. Or a server as a desktop. But the desktop eats resources your server would like to use. The desktop depends on the AMD/ATI ES1000 Graphics card. The server depend on it a lot less.

So ditch the desktop and use command line and web-based tools to manage the server.

2ndly: looking at the specs of this card... it is a server graphics card designed as an integrated solution for *remote server management*, it has a max of 64Mb memory and is lacking 3D support. It is NOT intended for a desktop. Not even back when it was sold, let alone an odd 10 years later.

That is also the reason you will not find any additional hardware for this card.

Using it for a desktop system is probably impossible with any type of desktop, not just Ubuntu. You really really need to ditch the desktop. Or use something else (that else might be Damn Small Linux)